# Answer without a question in review

Tags: discussion, support, bug

When I reviewed a question on SO [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6211903) an answer without a question.

[image]

How is this possible? Is this a bug, or am I not understanding something?

Comment: If you write complete words it aids people in understanding you... which is important...

Comment: I just hat exactly the same but with a different answer. It too was an audit.

Comment: When I look at it, I see the question. This is a 10k view deleted posts priv issue. Probably ought to have an exception for audit questions, or it sort of ruins the ruse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was an audit. Apparently, the question and answer were both deleted.

It looks like a bug though, because if it shows you the answer, it should also show the question.