# An answer without question or a question without answer

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, low-quality-posts

This has just popped in my VLQ queue:

[image]
I was more than sure, that this is an audit. I have selected "Look OK", because... **it looks OK**! There is nothing wrong with this answer in my opinion (correct me, if I'm wrong). I knew, that this is an audit (because of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276656/1469208) and because of missing question), but I marked, that it is OK, because I felt it is OK. Of course, I failed an audit.

What is even better, this is what I got along with message, that I failed:

[image]

It seems, that I found **two separate bugs** here:

- a **question without answer** or an **answer without question** should not appear as an audit (as explained [in mentioned post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276656/1469208)),
- I was **reviewing an answer** (without question), but I failed on **closed question** (without answer) -- this also sounds like a bug.

Can someone out of dev team verify this and reply, if there is any chance for fix / change to this?

Comment: This is indeed a bug. Answers on deleted questions simply shouldn't be chosen as audits (which is what's causing the display bugs here).

Comment: Agree with @animuson; a question being deleted carries pretty much no relevant information about the answer(s).

Comment: The first one is spam. Why do you need a question to delete spam?

Comment: @bjb568 Have you read my entire question with understanding? There is no "the first one" and "the second one". There's only one. I've been presented with first to review (an audit) and when I failed it, I was given another one. There's seems to be two bugs in here. One, which is using an answer on deleted question as an audit. And second one, which is showing different post (question) as an argument, to inform user, that he had failed an audit, when different post (an answer) was element being audited.

Comment: Oh, I misread. But you obviously chose the wrong action nonetheless.

Comment: @bjb568 Yes, you're right. But, I chose the wrong action _intentionally_, to see, what happens next (I was aware, that this is audit and what action is expected from me). Doing so, I was able to find two bugs at once.

Comment: A suggestion: if someone finds out these kind of bugs while reviewing, choose "Skip" option..

Comment: Possible cross site dupe [Don't use spam post as audits in the low quality review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647), the post you were reviewing was selected as audit probably because it was deleted as spam, in which case the audit itself is flawed.

Comment: @Braiam Up until now I had no idea, that something like _cross-site duplicates_ even exists. Am I really expected to check particular question on _all_ sites' metas before I post? Strange...

Comment: @trejder It's still kind of strange, I agree, but not *as* strange: the site you were linked to is meta.SE - the super-meta of the entire stack exchange, of which SO (and its meta) are just two of the many child sites. This meta is just weird in that it *used* to function as both the meta for SO and the meta for the entire SE, until they broke those apart a few months ago. Bug reports get reported in both site-level metas and the top-level meta, apparently by design, but it does lead to frequent dups of certain types of things. :p